# Significant figures between SI and non-SI units

Tags: sufficient-statistics, significant-figures

A person is running 10 km, and [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_of_length#Non-SI) states a US land mile corresponds to 1609.344 m.  Would it be more sensible to express the results as 6.21 miles or 6 miles?

The salient point I recognize here is the conversion is between data of SI and non-SI based units.

Comment: Significant figures are only an approximate way to keep track of relative precision.  If you believe that $10$ km has two significant figures, which I find quite reasonable, it is $\pm 0.5$ km or $\pm 5\%$. The implied range for $6.2$ mi is $\pm 0.8\%$.  This is fine in rough work.  To do it right, you should show the range as $\pm $ so much and the so much can be converted as well.

Comment: In practice, if it's an actual 10 km race, the distance is probably accurate to a relatively few meters or so (and thus should be written as e.g. 10.00 km if we were counting significant digits — but who does that in sports?). If the person just went out jogging and later measured their distance to be somewhere around 10 km, then qman's answer below seems reasonable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of digits used to express the number should reflect the precision.  Assuming that the '$0$' in '$10 \text{ km}$' is a significant digit, the precision is roughly $\pm 0.5 \text{ km}$, or $\pm 0.3 \text{ mi}$.  Expressing it as $6.2 \text{ mi}$ suggest a precision of about $\pm 0.05 \text{ mi}$, so normally the most appropriate way to write it would be $6 \text{ mi}$.  If you have reason to believe that the precision is greater, you could add decimal digits.  That there is a conversion is not relevant, only the deduced precision is.

Answer (score 1):

Writing quantities as integer numbers ending by zero should be avoided, because it is not clear how many significant figures are implied. Anyway, supposing $10$ km has $2$ significant digits (which is quite reasonable), I'd convert that to $6.2$ miles.